# Como restrinjo la vista la carpeta de images de mi proyecto

Tags: php, imagen, seguridad

He notado que en mi proyecto con tan solo escribir la ruta de mis imágenes estas se pueden apreciar fácilmente solo escribiendo la ruta en el navegador y no se si esto sea un error de seguridad.

La verdad es que me gustaría saber si existe una forma que cuando el usuario escriba esa ruta, lo redirija a la pagina index de mi proyecto. El proyecto esta escrito en **PHP**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad es que no se si esto sea algún error de seguridad y también me gustaría que me aclararan este ultimo punto para estar mejor enterado.

Comment: @phpMyGuel Hola amigo, la pregunta que me digirieron no respondió a mi pregunta, pero encontré algo que me ayudo a que no se muestren las imágenes si siquiera el código css de mi sitio web con un trozo de código que coloque en mi _.htaccess_ con este código: `IndexIgnore *` Ya con esto doy por finalizada esta pregunta, aunque fuera mucho mejor si existiera una forma de que me redirija a la pagina index a la misma vez que no me muestre nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para redirigir lo puedes hacer de varias formas, ya sea a través de htaccess con la sentencia
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
Y el .htaccess lo guardas en el escritorio de la carpeta de imágenes o bien con un documento index.php en la carpeta de imágenes y lo redireccionas al index con un header('Location:https//miweb.com');